# How to import XML Schema to excel with text data type for all the columns it creates? VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba, types

Automating the input of XML to excel: While importing the XML schema through VBA to excel, the excel is automatically taking the data type based on the data. How I can default the data type to be text for all the columns it imports?

Comment: "importing the XML schema through VBA to excel" doesn't tell us much about exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I am importing XML attribute-centric into excel and automated through VBA using ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport Url:= _ Fname, ImportMap:=Nothing, _ Overwrite:=False, Destination:=Range("$A$10")

This logic creates a table in excel and adds the XML data into it where I am not able to default the data type to "Text".

Comment: I'm not sure how much control you have without an explicit schema for the file you're importing.

Comment: Please [**edit**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65598943/edit) your post with all necessary code and data information and not in comments.